# importing a component in multiple module in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-module

I have a `SharedModule`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlMessagesComponent } from './control-messages.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ],
  declarations: [
    ControlMessagesComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    ControlMessagesComponent,
  ]
})

export class SharedModule {}
```

Then I imported in 2 different Modules:

```
import { SharedModule } from './../shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
      SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})

export class OnboardModule {}

import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [

  ],
  providers: [

  ]
})

export class AModule {}
```

Here is the `ControlMessagesComponent`

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ValidationService } from './../validators/validator';

@Component({
  selector: 'control-messages',
  template: `<div *ngIf="errorMessage !== null">{{errorMessage}}</div>`
})
export class ControlMessagesComponent {
  @Input() control: FormControl;
  constructor() {}

  get errorMessage() {
    for (const propertyName in this.control.errors) {
      if (this.control.errors.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) && this.control.touched) {
        return ValidationService.getValidatorErrorMessage(propertyName, this.control.errors[propertyName]);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

When I use it:
`<control-messages [control]="form.controls.assetName"></control-messages>`

I get the following error:

> Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. 
>   ("]*ngIf="errorMessage !==
>   null">{{errorMessage}}"):
>   ng:///SharedModule/ControlMessagesComponent.html@0:5
>       Property binding ngIf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and
>   all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations".  ("[ERROR
>   ->]{{errorMessage}}"): ng:///SharedModule/ControlMessagesComponent.html@0:0

I am out of options can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You might find this article helpful [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `CommonModule` to your `SharedModule`. `NgIf` and `NgForOf` are also directives which are in the `CommonModule`. Your Component which is actually in `SharedModule`, uses `NgIf`, so you must import it in your module.

[**Description**](https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule)

> The module that includes all the basic Angular directives like `NgIf`,
>   `NgForOf`,

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ControlMessagesComponent } from './control-messages.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
     CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ControlMessagesComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    ControlMessagesComponent,
  ]
})

export class SharedModule {}
```